# Grails i18n messages in html tags

Tags: html, grails, internationalization

how i can use i18n messages in html's input tag? for example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="${message(code:'placeholder.username')}"
```

to show placeholder text in several langs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="${message(code: 'placeholder.username')}">
```

Comment: It should work. What output you have? Is there any exception?

Comment: there's no any exception. but in input i see placeholder.username instead of username.

Comment: it's working. thanks. my safari in english, and i wrote only russian version in messages_ru, but didn't wrote in eng. firefox in russian and everything work fine.